# Different functions/images with similar Radon Transform

Tags: inverse-problems, radon-transform

A couple of days ago, I read somewhere (unfortunately can't find it anymore), that one cavet of inverse problems is that "similar looking" data $y$, given by
$$
\mathcal{A}x = y,
$$
where $\mathcal{A}$ is the Radon transform for example, can have very different sources $x$. I'm wondering if there is any mathematical construction of even a numerical example where functions/images $x_1, x_2$ look quite different, however the produced (noise free) data $y_1, y_2$ looks very similar.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: non unique radon transform gives a few hits.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Could you maybe also provide a reference or a link?